# Lightning component Collapsible and Accordion get id of the clicked section

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I cannot use lightning:accordion cause I need to show two fields on the label of the section. Right now, if I click on any section, it opens all sections
How can I open only the section I clicked & get Contact Id of the clicked section?

Component:

```
<div class="">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="con">
        <section class="slds-clearfix" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="{!c.sectionOne}">
            <div class="slds-grid  slds-grid_vertical-align-start">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
                    <div class="" >
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-show" aura:id="details" iconName="utility:chevronright" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates add"/>
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-hide" aura:id="details" iconName="utility:chevrondown" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates dash"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <ul class="">
                        <li class="slds-text-title_caps">{!con.Name} </li>
                        <li>{!con.Email} </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <div class="slds-float--right">
                        <lightning:button variant="base" label="EDIT" title="EDIT" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </section>

        <div class="slds-hide slds-p-around--medium" aura:id="details">
            {!con.Phone}
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getRecords(component);
},

sectionOne : function(component, event, helper) {
   helper.helper(component,event,'details');

},
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    var id = component.get("v.con");
    alert(id); 
},
```

})

Helper.js

```
({
getRecords : function(cmp) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.getContacts");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.contacts", response.getReturnValue());  
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

helper : function(component,event,secId) {
  var con = component.find(secId);
  con.forEach(function(element) {
        $A.util.toggleClass(element, "slds-hide");
  });
  $A.util.addClass(event.target, "slds-show");
}
```

})

Comment: You could use of a **HTML5** data attribute. You'll be able to pass the current iteration's record ID to the button(It might have to be a HTML Button) and retrieve the record Id in your controller.js

Comment: Why you are not using the one provided by Salesforce more info here [lightning:accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleAccordionConditional)

Comment: cause I have to show 2-3 fields as a list instead of a label  of the section